# Law of Clavius explained

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Law of Clavius states  $ \sim P \Rightarrow  P \vdash P$

And the only explanation I sort of understand is

`"If we ought to philosophise, then we ought to philosophise; and if we ought not to philosophise, then we ought to philosophise (i.e. in order to justify this view); in any case, therefore, we ought to philosophise."`

which to me reads as $(P \Rightarrow  P)\wedge (\sim P \Rightarrow P ) \vdash P   $
where P is "we ought to philosophise"
Which is not quite the same.

I am aware of the following relationship
$(\sim P \Rightarrow P ) \Leftrightarrow \; (\sim(\sim P)\; \vee \: P)$

and combining this with the above would basically be a form of "Or Elimination" or proof by cases. But this is just an explanation of how its proof would be worked out.

Anyway the above is more of a digression, but perhaps it may have some weight on my question. Really what I am interested in is an intuitive understanding of Clavius' law. What are some common examples in everyday logic?

Comment: To be clear, I understand the formal def, but would like some colloquial usage. The whole "we ought to philosophize"  example seemed liked "Or Elimination"

Comment: There are two possibilities: Either $P$, or $\lnot P$. But by the premise, if $\lnot P$, then $P$. So in either case, $P$.

Comment: [Clavius' Law](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Clavius's_Law) is a form of *reductio ad absurdum*: suppose $\neg P$. if you derive a contradiction from it (that is, $P$), then $P$ must be the case. (Note that it assumes the double-negation elimination rule, hence it's not intuitionistically valid).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

''Clavius' law'' is just a variant of proof by contradiction or [reductio ad absurdum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum): If $\sim\! P$ implies $P$, then $\sim\! P$ is inconsistent (because it then also implies the contradiction $\sim\! P\land P$). Therefore $P$.

Formally: $\sim\! P \Rightarrow P\vdash P$.

You should be able to formulate any proof by contradiction as an instance of Clavius'law, but it might read a bit awkward in some cases.

#### [Cantor's diagonal argument that $\mathbb R$ is not enumerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument#Uncountable_set), written as an instance of Clavius' law:

Assume you have an enumeration of $\mathbb R$. Then, by [diagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument#Uncountable_set) you can construct a real number that is not in that enumeration. Therefore you don't have an enumeration of $\mathbb R$. Therefore: $\mathbb R$ is not enumerable.

(Doubly negate the first premise to exactly match the logical form of Clavius' law, if you are picky.)

#### Argument against (absolute) Relativism, written as an instance of Clavius' law:

"No sentence is true" $\Rightarrow$ "There are true sentences" (for instance: "No sentence is true"). Therefore there are true sentences. [ref](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequentia_mirabilis#Beispiel)

Comment: I don't understand how you can have a contradiction without a conjunction, or without having some proposition "p" and another "not p".  You don't have either of those in the law of Clavius.

Comment: Well, write reductio in law form as $\sim\!P \Rightarrow (\sim \!Q\land Q) \vdash P$ for any $P,Q$. In any minimal deductive system it is interderivable with Clavius' law: First assume the reductio law and the premise of Clavius' law, $\sim\!P\Rightarrow P$. From there infer $\sim\! P\Rightarrow (P\land\sim\! P)$ and by reductio $P$, the conclusion of Clavius' law. Conversely, assume Clavius' law and $\sim\!P \Rightarrow (\sim \!Q\land Q)$. Using ex falso ($(Q\land \sim\! Q)\vdash P$, for any $Q,P$) we can infer $\sim\! P\Rightarrow P$ and then by Clavius' law $P$, the conclusion of reductio.

Comment: Consequently Clavius' law is, like reductio, intuitionistically invalid.

Comment: In laymans terms you assume ~p, derive p as per standard normal fwd proofs go, conditionalize, use clavius' law and conclude p.

Comment: i.e. Clavius' law is more general than contradiction rule.

Comment: Not sure why it is more general. Are you saying there are cases where I could exclusively use Clavius' law, but not e.g. the contradiction rule?

Comment: @lodrik There do exist cases where you can use the law of Clavius without using the contradiction rule.  See my answer and the theorem that Euclid proved.

Comment: @skyfire I'm not sure what you mean by "more general".  My understanding goes that a formula "Prop1" is more general than a formula " Prop2 " if and only if given Prop1 we can derive Prop2, but given Prop2 we can't derive Prop1.  If you have the deduction meta-theorem and the law of Clavius, you can't derive the formula CCNpqCCNpNqp, which embodies proof by contradiction.  I found a model which indicates this using Mace4.  Just consider the model where C00 = 1, C01 = 1, C10 = 0, C11 = 1, N0 = 1 and N1 = 1.  Suppose that p = 1 and q = 1 to find how CCNpqCCNpNqp fails.

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood Sorry, i meant cases where you can't easily replace the one by the other. There aren't, as they are so similar. In your example you could directly appeal to reductio instead of Clavius' law.

Comment: No you are right, I suppose they are equivalent. My approach to RAA is to Assume 'p' , ...derive q and NOT q (or possibly just NOT p) use contradictory premises rule to infer NOT p, conditionalize to obtain p implies NOT p and then use Clavius' law to conclude NOT p. ( or similiarly with starting from NOT p) so in my mind this is the whole RAA method whereas Clavius' law only requires the premise NOT p implies p to infer p. Also Sry I do not have any experience in polish notation to understand your answers. Perhaps you can provide me with a link on how it's used.

Comment: @skyfire I've added a link to an entry on Polish notation.

Answer (score 2):

Clavius Law aka Consequentia Mirabilis is an instance of the more common Proof by Cases. Proof by Cases is the axiom schema:

/* Proof by Cases */
(¬ B → A) → ((B → A) → A)

If you now instantiate B = A, you get:

/* Clavius Law aka Consequentia Mirabilis */
(¬ A → A) → A

Interestingly you can go backwards and derive Proof by Cases from Consequentia Mirabilis as well. The interderivability
holds over minimal logic. The instantiation B = A is also mentioned here:

**Aristotle and the Consequentia Mirabilis**
William Kneale - 1957
https://www.jstor.org/stable/628635?seq=1

Answer (score 1):

" ∼P⇒P⊢P"

You can read this as meaning "Suppose that the negation of a proposition implies that proposition.  It follows that the proposition is provable."

Or equivalently in [Polish notation](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lukasiewicz/polish-notation.html):

CNpp $\vdash$ p.

No one less than Aristotle himself did not understand the law of Clavius.

With the principle of bivalence in mind, the only way that the negation of a proposition can imply a proposition is when the proposition is true also.  We'll informally prove this by contradiction.

Suppose that 'CNpp' is true (1).  Suppose that 'p' is false (0).  Then

CNpp = CN00.

CN00 = C10.

C10 = 0.

Thus, CNpp will end up as false.  But, this contradicts our first hypothesis, and thus we conclude that 'p' is true when 'CNpp' is true.  Therefore, the law of Clavius is correct.

The law of Clavius got used by Euclid when proving a theorem of number theory.  p. 50-51 of J. Lukasiewicz's book on Aristotle's Syllogistic reads as follows:

"If the product of two integers, a and b, is divisible by a prime number n, then if a is not divisible by n, b should be divisible by n'.  Let us now suppose that a = b and the product a x a (a^2) is divisible by n.  It results from this supposition that 'If a is not divisible by n, then a is divisible by n'.  Here we have an example of a true implication of the antecedent of which is the negation of the consequent.  From this implication Euclid derives the theorem: 'If a^2 is divisible by a prime number n, then a is divisible by n.'

Or in more symbolic notation the ideas might get rendered as follows:

Suppose ab | n, and n is prime.  Then if a | n is false, b | n is true.  Suppose that a = b.  Thus, aa | n.  It follows that if a | n is false, a | n is true.  Consequently let us suppose that aa | n, and n is prime.  Then by the law of Clavius a | n is true.

As an example of the application of the theorem, since 36 is divisible by 3, it follows that 6 is divisible by 3.  Or as one which might not seem too obvious, 50,625 is square.  It's divisible by the prime number 5.  So,

(50,625 / 5) = 10,125 is divisible by 5.  Also, 50,625 is divisible by 3.  So, 50,625 / 3 = 16,875 which is divisible by 3 also.

Additionally, the law of Clavius is a "weak" law.  In other words, we can reverse the turnstile.  Not only do we have

CNpp $\vdash$ p

but we also have

p $\vdash$ CNpp.

Thus, anytime you have a subformula of the type "CNpp" in any formula, you can replace it by a subformula of the type "p" anywhere in the formula and the truth value of the formula will not change.  Or instead of evaluating shorter formulas, you can evaluate longer formulas by replacing any instance of a subformula of the type 'p' with a subformula of the type 'CNpp' in the formula, and the truth value of the formula will not change.

The law of Clavius can also get applied to determining whether or not a formula is a tautology, if it has only conditional and negation symbols (and variables or constants).  The general pattern goes to assume that such a formula is not a tautology.  Then you show that under that assumption it is a tautology.  Discharging the hypothesis we have an implication which gives us the left-hand side of the law of Clavius.  We thus conclude that the formula in mind is a tautology.

For example, suppose that we want to prove that

C CCpqr C Crp C s p

is a tautology.

We'll assume that it's not a tautology.  Under that assumption, the consequent is false.  Or in symbols we have that

C Crp C s p = 0.

If C Crp C s p = 0, then

Crp = 1 and

C s p = 0.

If C s p = 0, then

--> s = 1

and

--> p = 0.

Crp = 1 also, so

--> r = 0.

Since p = 0,

Cpq = 1.

Since Cpq = 1 and r  = 0,

CCpqr = 0.

Thus, if C Crp C s p = 0, CCpqr = 0 also.

It follows that C CCpqr C Crp C s p = 1.

Thus, from the assumption of C CCpqr C Crp C s p not being a tautology, we've found that C CCpqr C Crp C s p is a tautology.  Discharging the hypothesis we have that if C CCpqr C Crp C s p is not a tautology, then it is a tautology.  By the law of Clavius we now conclude that C CCpqr C Crp C s p is a tautology.

Note that we didn't use proof by contradiction here in the form of deriving "p and not p", because nowhere did we derive a conjunction.  Nor did we derive two conditionals, one of which implies a proposition, and the other it's negation.  And you CANNOT logically infer from a proposition and it's negation, any tautology directly (you have to do more work first).

Meta-theorem:

If a formula is a tautology, and it is a conditional, it can get informally proved using the method indicated above using the law of Clavius.  Thus, if you want more practice with the law of Clavius, I'll suggest picking any conditional which any textbook says is a tautology and proving it in a way similar to the above.  For example, try proving that any of the following are tautologies using the above method and the law of Clavius

CCpqCCqrCpr, CpCNpq, CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr, CCpCpqCpq, CCpqCCrpCrq, CCNpqCCNpNqp, CCpCqrCqCpr.